# Windows Phone load from database

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have created application and connected DB through WCF, loaded in the Main Page the names of products(first column of DB).

How can I realize that:

> When I click on "Orange" the ItemInfoPage is opened and the information from columns 2, 3 is loaded to the page

**Example**

*DB:*

```
Name     Color     Number
Orange   Orange    25
Apricot  Yellow    14
Apple    Red       18
```

*MainPage.xaml:*

```
Things:
Orange click--> ItemInfo.xaml opens --> Color: Orange, Number: 25 is loaded on page
Apricot click--> ItemInfo.xaml opens --> Color: Yellow, Number: 14 is loaded on page
Apple click--> ItemInfo.xaml opens --> Color: Red, Number: 18 is loaded on page
```

Code from MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StudentDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudentDataTemplate}"
             Height="Auto"
             Width="460"
             Margin="10,10,0,0" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Name="ListBox1"/>
        <Button Click="navigateitem" 
Content="Button" 
Height="72"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="142,351,0,0" 
Name="button1" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="160" />
    </Grid>
```

How can I load the Color and Number columns for necessary item?

**How can I load data from the necessary row of table?**

Comment: StackOverflow is a site meant to help user on their code. We are not a website to do task for you. Please take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com you have to show us stuff YOU tried if you want us to help you on that piece of broken code, not ask us to realise something at your place.

Comment: You're probably looking for the DataContext property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) and Navigate method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigate.aspx).

Comment: ok, I'll rephrase my question:
How can I load data from the necessary row of table?

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look here and start with a simple copy/paste example to undersand

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876(v=vs.105).aspx